# how to solve this problem? ( Euclid Geometric )

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, angle

Condition: For the quadrilateral $ABCD$, we have
$BC=CD=DA$, and two angles are given: $\widehat{ADC}=96^\circ$, $\widehat{BCD}=48^\circ$.

Problem: Which is the measure of the angle $\widehat{ABC}$?

[image: Quadrilateral ABCD]

I can't solve this problem... I got an answer "162" by drawing it and measuring it, but I don't know how the answer came out Logically.

[image: Own try to solve the problem]

As I pondered it, I think it would be enough to show that the point $H$ is the circumcenter of $A'B'C$, but I could not prove it. How do you get $X$?

Comment: I would start by joining the points B and D with a line. Figure out the length $BD$ first (I got it to be equal to $2L\cdot \cos 66^{\circ}$)

Comment: In fact, you can find two isosceles triangles in the quadrilateral, which will give you some angle information, and you know that the four angles of a quadrilateral add to what?

Comment: This post starts from a beautiful problem, so i edited it to have the pictures shown as such, not as links. Please check if the edited lines reflect the intention of the intital post. Unfortunately the notations in the two pictures, (the given problem and the own tries,) differ substantially and may lead to confusions. You may please want to edit again, so that the construction of the auxiliary points in the second picture are done in an explained order with explained properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The angle of vertices in a pentagon is $108°$, this is the main key to solve this problem.
After constructing a pentagon as shown in this diagram, we notice that the line segment $ED$ is a symmetry line of the pentagon and because $AD=BE$, then $\Delta ABF$ and $\Delta DEF$ are two similar isosceles triangles.

Thus: $\widehat {ABC} = 54°+108°=162°$.

[image]

Comment: wow I couldn't even imagine the regular pentagon. however, why ED is a symmetry line of the pentagon? Knowing that, I'll be able to understand your solution. Of course, thanks to this, I solved this problem. When I got several angles, I found that AD and the segment of the pentagon are parallel, and I solved this problem using that.

Comment: @growww, Do you see that equilateral triangle (one side is $CD$)? $E$ is connected to $D$ which is the vertex of that equilateral triangle. $ED$ and the perpendicular bisector of that triangle are collinear. I hope you see why the $ED$ is the symmetry line of the pentagon.

Comment: @ Seyed I understood your words well. This is a problem that I had been thinking about for a day, but it was solved. It's all thanks to you.

Comment: Why do we have trivially the similarity of $\Delta ABF$ and $\Delta DEF$? (It is not really a good idea to give the solution as part of a picture.)

Comment: OK, why...?! (1) Just try to edit the solution in order to make clear the similarity. (2) Note that on this site other users are generally allowed to EDIT already given answers. An edit is impossible in the above case. Giving the missing argument in a comment is not really wanted. (3) Then imagine that your picture, hosted at https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQMjL.png is lost for some reasons. This happens sometimes, in my case many times on imgur. Then your whole story is lost. Enough reasons? Shall we ask a third party?

Comment: @Seyed: Another few points about "imaged" text: (4) It's impossible to search. (So, if years down the line someone thinks "Oh, hey, I vaguely remember some clever solution involving a line of symmetry in a pentagon", they won't easily be able to find this specific answer.) Moreover, (5) visually-impaired users can't use screen-reading technology to read imaged text, nor can they improve legibility with a white-text-on-black-background inversion, etc. Also, (6) readers cannot select-and-copy the text for quotations or citations or whatever. ... In general, it's just best for text to be text.

Comment: Please use a less provocative way to comment. (I will not comment on your "question" above.) Many of the above other comments are at object. As far as i see, this answer still uses a picture with text, the final answer is at any rate in the picture. The text from the picture is now also copied in the answer. Let's say that the construction of the points $E,F$ is clear, and that the reader finds her or his way to exhibit in the right order the marked angles, except for those that finally matter. This still does not makes clear why the two triangles claimed to be similar are indeed similar.

Comment: @dan_fulea, The reason that those two triangles are similar is very very simple. Triangle $FDE$ is isosceles and we already know that the $AD=BE$ therefore the triangle $ABF$ is isosceles too and similar to triangle $FDE$. I hope it is clear for you now.

Comment: It was clear for me also some hours ago. But to understand the point of the comment... Your argument is as follows, explained in detail. You know and *use implicitly* (i) $\Delta FDE$ is isosceles, but not mention it. Then we connect this with (ii) $AD=BE$. This implies (iii) $\Delta ABF$ isosceles, not mentioned. This implies (iv) $\Delta ABF\sim\Delta FDE$, and only (iv) is mentioned, then used to get (iii). There is some order of things when collecting and exposing arguments. It was so much missing above, initially we had a picture & some arguments, the reader had to get things right...

Comment: @dan_fulea, I don't have time to argue with you at all. My answer to the question was very clear to the OP. If the solution was clear for you some hours ago!! it is fine, good for you and I am happy that you got the point. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more solution, which tries to use the idea to attack the problem as in the OP. In particular, i will use the points $C$ and $H$ from the second picture in the OP, they lead immediately to a solution.
(This $C$ will be denoted below by $E$ to avoid the confusion with the point $C$ from the given quadrilateral. So $E$ is constructed so that $ADCE$ is a parallelogram. It turns out that $H$ is indeed the circumcenter of $\Delta BCE$, and the points $A,B,H$ are colinear.)

---

Let us construct the point $E$, so that $ADCE$ is a parallelogram. Its angles in $D,E$ have measure $96^\circ$ each, its angles in $A,C$ have $84^\circ$ each.

We further construct $X$ in the interior of the parallelogram $ADCE$ (or in the half-plane containing $C,D$ w.r.t. the line $AE$) so that $\Delta AEX$ is equilateral.

Then the angles
$\widehat {XEC}$,
and respectively
$\widehat {BCE}$ have measure $96^\circ-60^\circ=36^\circ$, and $86^\circ-48^\circ=36^\circ$. This information, joined with the equality (of lengths) of segments $BC=CE=EX$, implies that ($\Delta ECX=\Delta BCE$, that $BXCE$ is an isosceles trapezium with "easy angles", and finally that) these segments are three of the diagonals of a regular pentagon. Let $Y$ be the missing vertex of this pentagon, although not needed in the proof.
Let $H$ be the circumcenter of the above regular pentagon.

It is time to display the picture so far:

[image: stackexchange question 4095374]

Then the symmetries of the two marked regular polygons w.r.t. the common side $EX$ show that on the perpendicular bisector $(d)$ of $EX$ there are the points $B,H$ (pentagon symmetry) and $A$ (equilateral symmetry). From the collinearity of $A,B,H$, and since the angle built by $(d)$ with the direction $AD\|CE\|BX$ is $\widehat{HBX}=\frac 12\widehat{EBX}=\frac12 108^\circ=54^\circ$, we obtain the angle in $A$ in $ABCD$, and finally the angle in $B$, which is $360^\circ-(48^\circ+96^\circ+54^\circ)=\color{blue}{162^\circ}$, as claimed in the OP.

$\square$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Calculate AC by SSA in triangle ADC. Reduce angle at C by the calculated amount.

As two sides and  the non-included angle is given for the remaining triangle ABC we have two solutions by *the ambiguous case*.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I had proposed in my early comment that the question might be resolved using isosceles triangles (since the geometry seemed to suggest this rather strongly).  A challenge arises, but not in the way I thought it would...

The two isosceles triangles that can be marked within the quadrilateral permit us to determine measures for all of the angles indicated.  Two which cannot be found by this ploy alone will be identified as $ \ m(\angle BAC) = \theta \ $ and $ \ m(\angle ABD) = \phi \ \ . $  We *are* able to say at this point that $ \ \phi + \theta \ = \ 108º \ \ . $

[image]

Dividing the quadrilateral with $ \ \overline{BD} \ $ separates in into one of the isosceles triangles and another triangle. We will call the length of the congruent sides $ \ s \ \ , $ the length of $ \ \overline{BD} \ $ will be $ \ Y \ \ . $ and the length of the non-congruent side of the quadrilateral is $ \ X \ \ . $  The Law of Sines then permits us to write the relations

$$ \frac{\sin 66º}{s} \  =  \ \frac{\sin 48º}{Y} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \frac{\sin \phi}{s} \  =  \ \frac{\sin 30º}{X}  \  =  \ \frac{\sin (42º + \theta)}{Y} \ \ . $$

[image]

We do this also with the segment $ \ \overline{AC} \ $ to which we assign the length $ \ Z \ $ .  From the Law of Sines, we have

$$ \frac{\sin 42º}{s} \  =  \ \frac{\sin 96º}{Z} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \frac{\sin \theta}{s} \  =  \ \frac{\sin 6º}{X}  \  =  \ \frac{\sin (66º + \phi)}{Z} \ \ . $$

We can now bring this ratios together to obtain

$$ X \  =  \ \frac{\sin 30º}{\sin \phi} · s \  =  \ \frac{\sin 6º}{\sin \theta} · s  \ \ , \ \ Y \  =  \ \frac{\sin 48º}{\sin 66º} · s \  =  \ \frac{\sin (42º + \theta)}{\sin \phi} · s  \ \ ,   $$
$$ Z \  =  \ \frac{\sin 96º}{\sin 42º} · s \  =  \ \frac{\sin (66º + \phi)}{\sin \theta} · s  \ \ .  $$

This is where the difficulty in this approach emerges, as we have a plethora of information with no clear guide as to how to make use of it.  If *all* we cared about was getting an answer to the problem, we can easily produce expressions from which we can *compute* angles, such as

$$ \frac{\sin 96º}{\sin 42º} \ = \  \frac{2 \sin 48º \cos 48º}{\cos 48º}  \  =  \ 2  \sin 48º \ = \ \frac{\sin (66º + \phi)}{\sin \theta}     $$
$$  \Rightarrow \ \ 2  \sin 48º  \sin \theta \ = \ \sin 66º \cos \phi  \ + \ \cos 66º \sin \phi \ \ , $$
which together with
$$ \frac{\sin 30º}{\sin \phi}  \  =  \ \frac{\sin 6º}{\sin \theta} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \sin 30º · \sin \theta \ = \ \sin 6º · \sin \phi \ \ \Rightarrow \ \sin \theta \ = \ 2 \sin 6º · \sin \phi $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 4  \sin 48º · \sin 6º · \sin \phi \ = \ \sin 66º \cos \phi  \ + \ \cos 66º \sin \phi    $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \tan \phi \ = \ \frac{\sin 66ª}{4  \sin 48º · \sin 6º \ - \ \cos 66º} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \phi \ = \ -84º \ \ \text{or} \ \ 96º  $$
very precisely by a calculator.  We can achieve similar sorts of equations for $ \ \phi \ \ \text{or} \ \ \theta \ \ . $  (I had initially believed, because all of the marked angles are multiples of 6º or 12º, that double-angle and half-angle relations would be far more helpful than they turned out to be.)

But it would be more *satisfying* mathematically if we can obtain an exact result.  The best option (after various attempts) seems to be simply to apply  $ \ \sin \theta \ = \ 2 \sin 6º · \sin \phi  \ $ and exploit its resemblance to the double-angle formula for sine, taking $ \ \sin \phi \ = \ \cos 6º \ $ and so $ \ \sin \theta \ = \ \sin ( 2 · 6º) \ \Rightarrow \ \theta \ = \ 12º \ \ . $  From that, we have $ \ \phi \ = \ 108º - \theta \ = \ 96º \ \ , $ which is consistent with
$ \ \sin 96º \ = \ \cos 6º \ $ and with all the other ratio equations we established earlier.

Hence, we may conclude that $ \ m(\angle ABC) \ = \ 66º + \phi \ = \ 66º + 96º \ = \ 162º \ \ . $